# Changing a limited user account in XP fails

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
public class ChangePassword
{
   public static void Main()
   {    
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "someLimitedAccount");
    user.ChangePassword( "xxx", "zzz" );
   }
}
```

This works just fine with administrator accounts, but seems to crash like so when I try to change limited accounts in XP:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
   at ChangePassword.Main()
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how?

EDIT #1:
I added the following:
`Console.WriteLine( "user: " + user );`

Below this line:
`UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "someLimitedAccount");`

And I get this:
user:

It doesn't *look* like user is null when I print it, but then again I'm not really a .Net guy - I seem to remember this being expected behavior.

Comment: What call is throwing the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: it most probably is the user, as context would result in `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Hmm, my guess is that it is the user. I'll edit for some new analysis.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that's definitely *not* expected behavior. If you're running from a debug build, you should see an indication of exactly where the exception is being thrown - but it looks like the line beginning with `user.ChangePassword(...`.  It's likely that `FindByIdentity isn't happy with "someLimitedAccount" in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct user name?  [`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383475.aspx) returns `null` if there is no match.

With that same kind of code, I'm able to find local Administrator and Limited accounts on both Windows 7 and XP machines (as a .NET 4.0 Client app).  It appears to be case insensitive but must be the short name, not the full name.  Anything else yields `null`.

You can get a listing of all local valid user names, you can use the following code:

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var up = new UserPrincipal(pc);
var users = new PrincipalSearcher(up).FindAll();
foreach (var user in users)
    Console.WriteLine(user);
```

Combined with the test code:

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var up = new UserPrincipal(pc);
var users = new PrincipalSearcher(up).FindAll();
foreach (var u in users)
    Console.WriteLine(u.Name);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("User: ");
var name = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, name);
if (user == null)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} not found", name);
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", user.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: {0}", user.DisplayName);
}
```

And some sample outputs

```
__vmware_user__
Administrator
Guest
Jeff
Share

User: jeff
Name: Jeff
DisplayName: Jeff M
...
User: nonuser
nonuser not found
...
User: guest
Name: Guest
DisplayName:
```

Comment: Is there a way to list the user names so I can see if it is something I am not expecting? I've tried prefixing it with the machine name and the domain as well and I can't seem to get it to come back with anything. (+1) regardless :)

Comment: Freakin' sweet - I'll have to run it on the PC in question and post back. Now to translate it back to C#... :)

Comment: Man - you rock! Thanks so much. You were right, the display name and the name fields were different on the account in question :( Is there a way to see this in the windows UI somewhere? Thanks again!

Comment: @java: Haha I had that in my comment but opted to delete when I found a way in code.  The way I know of (if you have XP Pro) is to open "Computer Management" (Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Computer Management) and expand the "System Tools\Local Users and Groups\Users" tree.  You will see a listing of available Users there.  I don't recall how to get to an equivalent window on XP Home or of any other way (that doesn't involve 3rd party tools) so I won't be able to help you if that's what you have.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you had it once and then it was gone. I was thinking...dang! :)